# How to create grid/pan on Angular like Miro with zoom

Tags: angular, canvas, grid, pan

I'd like to create a basic diagram app where I can basically create different shapes on a grid. The basic functionalities I'd like to implement are the zoom in zoom out (with a grid as background). But the size of the squares has to adapt to the screen.
I am using `ngx-panzoom` on Angular (and managed to zoom in/out) but I am struggling to set the background (I've tried to set an vector graphic but it didn't work well).

Also how can I retrieve the position of a diagram (in the future)?

It has to look like the Miro app.

I've heard of `ej2-angular-diagram` but can only use the free trial version. Do you know other libraries I can use in order to do this?

Thank you!